# SignalR values with Kendo UI Asp.net wrappers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo UI datawiz component, RadialGauge, which I would like to feed with real time data. It's setup using the asp.net wrappers, like so (snipped from kendo demos):

```
    <div id="gauge-container-center">
        @(Html.Kendo().RadialGauge()
              .Name("tensionGauge")
              .Pointer(pointer => pointer.Value(28))
              .Scale(scale => scale
                                  .MinorUnit(5)
                                  .StartAngle(-60)
                                  .EndAngle(240)
                                  .Max(180)
                                  .Labels(labels => labels
                                                        .Position(GaugeRadialScaleLabelsPosition.Inside)
                                  )
                                  .Ranges(ranges =>
                                      {
                                          ranges.Add().From(80).To(120).Color("#ffc700");
                                          ranges.Add().From(120).To(150).Color("#ff7a00");
                                          ranges.Add().From(150).To(180).Color("#c20000");
                                      })
              )
              )

    </div>
```

All the underlying functionality is for "real time" data is setup and working fine. My only issue is how I would go about feeding the signalR value into the `.Pointer(pointer => pointer.Value(signalRValueHere)` part. Any suggestions on how to do this? It doesn't seem to be an abundance of examples combining these two frameworks yet, so search results are scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this using a different approach. I opted to use the javascript-initializer instead, allowing me to utilize SignalR-values in the script.

```
            function createGauge() {
                $("#tensionGauge").kendoRadialGauge({
                    pointer: {
                        value: 0,
                        color: "black",
                    },
                    cap: {
                        color: "white",
                        size: 1
                    },
                    scale: {
                        minorUnit: 50,
                        majorUnit: 100,
                        startAngle: -50,
                        endAngle: 230,
                        min: @Convert.ToInt32(Model.MinTensionRange),
                        max: @Convert.ToInt32(Model.MaxTensionRange),
                        labels: {
                            position: "inside"
                        },
                        ranges: [ // TODO: Fetch limits from signalR or Model
                            {
                                from: 300,
                                to: 100, 
                                color: "#ffc700"
                            },{
                                from: -300,
                                to: -100, 
                                color: "#ffc700"
                            }, {
                                from: @Convert.ToInt32(Model.MinTensionRange),
                                to: -300, 
                                color: "#c20000"
                            },{
                                from: @Convert.ToInt32(Model.MaxTensionRange),
                                to: 300, 
                                color: "#c20000"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                createGauge();
            });
```

And the js-part to update the value:

```
messageHub.client.notifyTension = function (tensionMessage) {
    $('#tensionGauge').data("kendoRadialGauge").value(tensionMessage);
};
```